# Given $m$ vectors, is the sum of all possible inner products between them nonnegative?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I'm trying to solve the following problem from *Linear Algebra Done Right*, by Sheldon Axler.

> Prove or give a counterexample: if $v_1, \dots , v_m \in V$, then
> $$\sum_{j = 1}^{m}\sum_{k = 1}^{m}\langle v_j, v_k \rangle \geq 0.$$

I don't know if the statement is true, so all I've done so far is try to manipulate the expression:
$$\sum_{j = 1}^{m}\sum_{k = 1}^{m}\langle v_j, v_k \rangle = \sum_{j = k}^{}\sum_{k = 1}^{m} \langle v_j, v_k \rangle + \sum_{j \neq k}^{}\sum_{k = 1}^{m}\langle v_j, v_k \rangle = \sum_{j = 1}^{m} \langle v_j, v_j \rangle + 2 \sum_{k > j} \Re(\langle v_j, v_k \rangle),$$
whose first term is nonnegative, by defintion of inner product. However, I can't say anything about the second term. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: With $w=\sum_k v_k$ the expression can be written as $ \langle w,w \rangle$.

Comment: if $G$ is the Gram matrix, then $G \succeq \mathbf 0$ so $\mathbf 1^* G \mathbf 1 \geq 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here comes down to the linearity of the dot-product:
$$
\sum_{j = 1}^{m}\sum_{k = 1}^{m}\left\langle v_j, v_k \right\rangle
= 
\sum_{j = 1}^{m}\left\langle v_j, \sum_{k = 1}^{m}v_k \right\rangle
= 
\left\langle\sum_{j = 1}^{m} v_j, \sum_{k = 1}^{m}v_k \right\rangle
$$
That is, the expression can be written as $\langle w,w\rangle$ where $w = \sum_{j = 1}^{m} v_j$.